# ASP.NET MVC EF-Migrations - How to create a SCRIPT from the dataBase with tables and all saved records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Im using micrations, and i can save a script from the dataBase with the tables, but i need to create a script with all the data saved in the DB.

What would be the command to create this script with all saved data?

Comment: That's not what migrations are for. You can to do that, for example, from the SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: ok, I thought that as there was the option to create the Script of the tables there was also the option to create the SCRIPT with the data

Comment: Migrations have the option to [Seed](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx) data for lookup tables, test data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Management Studio, right click on your database.

Select Tasks -> Generate Scripts.
On 'Set Scripting Options', click 'Advanced'
Under 'General', set 'Types of data to script' to True